# $? -ne 0 Not Working

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I've been trying to create a fancy oh-my-zsh theme, but unfortunately I've hit an annoying roadblock.

```
eval gray='$FG[245]'
yellow='226'
ret=$?
# error check
[[ $ret -ne 0 ]] && yellow='100'#THIS LINE NOT FUNCTIONING
#prompt
PROMPT='$gray%~ $(git_prompt_info)${FG[$yellow]}%(!. ⚡ .»)%{$reset_color%}'
RPROMPT='$gray%n:%m%{$reset_color%}$?'
```

This is what I have so far, line six doesn't work though, I've tried single brackets, I've tried adding running it as sh and not as zsh, I've also tried swapping $ret for $? and even moving the whole thing to a full if-then setup, so far, none of it has worked. Did I screw up the syntax somehow, or will it just not work due to the environment or implementation?

Note:
This is oh-my-zsh so this config file is to modify the command prompt of the terminal, $? being the return value of the last run command.

Comment: Shouldn't you use double quotes?

Comment: Why don't you use `%?` to get the return code of the last executed command prior to the prompt?

Comment: In case you're interested in `%?`, read `man zshmisc`, section `SIMPLE PROMPT ESCAPES`: "%? The return status of the last command executed just before the prompt.". It won't break in the same way that `$?` the way you're using it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
yellow='226'
```

This always succeeds and $? is 0 afterwards.

Comment: This in a theme file for oh-my-zsh, note the $? in the last line, I added that to check the output; since this is a modifier for the command prompt $? refers to the return value of the last command I ran.

Comment: @Slowki: Right, but you use $? in the middle of your script. You test $? being not equal to 0, but at the place you test it, it is always equal to 0 because `yellow='226'` always succeeds.

Comment: Specifically, you set `ret=$?` following the assignment to `yellow`, then test `[[ $ret -ne 0 ]]`

Comment: I'll take this as the best answer since it's applicable to other scripts, but in this case of theme files for oh-my-zsh it doesn't work.

Comment: @Slowki: If you don't think this answer works for your question, then please un-accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Roger is right, the failing line is useless. However, I believe your primary issue is that you are using single quotes, and the string substitution is not happening.

```
$ a=foo

$ echo "$a"
foo

$ echo '$a'
$a
```

So, use double quotes! Single quotes are for literals.